# How to use mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this:

```
{'speed':45, 'time':1446271000},   
{'speed':45, 'time':1446271001},   
{'speed':63, 'time':1446271002},    
{'speed':68, 'time':1446271003},  
{'speed':70, 'time':1446271004},    
{'speed':59, 'time':1446271005},   
{'speed':55, 'time':1446271006},    
{'speed':61, 'time':1446271007},    
{'speed':62, 'time':1446271008},   
{'speed':63, 'time':1446271009},    
{'speed':67, 'time':1446271010}
```

I want to summarise the high speed (speed >=60) records, so the result should look like:

```
{'speed':63,'duration':2,'start': 1446271002,'end': 1446271004}  
{'speed':61,'duration':3,'start': 1446271007,'end': 1446271010}
```

How should I achieve this?

Comment: do you want the results to be sorted by start time?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following aggregation pipeline which does an initial **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** to filter out those documents that are less than 60.

The next pipeline step uses the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** operator to re-order the documents by the time field which is necessary for the next step, i.e. the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline. In here that's where you derive the start and end fields through the use of the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** and **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** accumulator operators that extract the first and last times when you group the documents by the speed field as the key.

The last pipeline step **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** creates the additional field, duration using the **[`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#exp._S_subtract)** arithmetic operator which, as the name implies, subtracts the `start` from the `end` times. The final pipeline would look like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "speed": { "$gte": 60 } } },
    { "$sort": { "time": 1 }  },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$speed",
            "start": { "$first": "$time" },
            "end": { "$last": "$time" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "speed": "$_id",
            "duration": { "$subtract": [ "$end", "$start" ] },
            "start": 1,
            "end": 1
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output:**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "start" : 1446271010,
            "end" : 1446271010,
            "speed" : 67,
            "duration" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "start" : 1446271007,
            "end" : 1446271007,
            "speed" : 61,
            "duration" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "start" : 1446271008,
            "end" : 1446271008,
            "speed" : 62,
            "duration" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "start" : 1446271004,
            "end" : 1446271004,
            "speed" : 70,
            "duration" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "start" : 1446271003,
            "end" : 1446271003,
            "speed" : 68,
            "duration" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "start" : 1446271002,
            "end" : 1446271009,
            "speed" : 63,
            "duration" : 7
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: After you add $sort stage, it will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this because the existing answer add unnecessary [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) stage to the pipeline which will result in the drop of performance.

You need to filter out all document in your collection where `speed` is [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) 60 using the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator then [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your document by "speed" and use the [`$min`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#grp._S_min) and [`$max`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max) accumulator operators which respectively return the mimimum and maximum value for "time" for distinct group. From there you need to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)ion stage in other to calculate to "duration" using the [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#exp._S_subtract) operator. Of course the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method provides access to the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/).

```js
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$match": { 
        "speed": { "$gte": 60 } 
    }}, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$speed", 
        "duration": { "$sum": 1 }, 
        "start": { "$min": "$time" }, 
        "end": { "$max": "$time" }
    }},
    { "$project": { 
        "speed": "$_id", 
        "_id": 0, 
        "duration": { "$subtract": [ "$end", "$start" ] }, 
        "start": 1, 
        "end": 1 
    }} 
])
```

Which yield:

```js
{ "start" : 1446271010, "end" : 1446271010, "speed" : 67, "duration" : 0 }
{ "start" : 1446271008, "end" : 1446271008, "speed" : 62, "duration" : 0 }
{ "start" : 1446271007, "end" : 1446271007, "speed" : 61, "duration" : 0 }
{ "start" : 1446271004, "end" : 1446271004, "speed" : 70, "duration" : 0 }
{ "start" : 1446271003, "end" : 1446271003, "speed" : 68, "duration" : 0 }
{ "start" : 1446271002, "end" : 1446271009, "speed" : 63, "duration" : 7 }
```